# Parallel processing in Julia throws errors

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

My understanding is that parallelization is included by default in a base Julia installation.

However, when I try to use it, I am getting errors that the functions and macros are not defined. For example:

`nprocs()`

Throws an error:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: nprocs not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Nowhere in any Julia documentation can I find mention of any packages that need to be included in order to use these functions. Am I missing something here?

I am using Julia version 1.0.5 inside the JuliaPro/Atom IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know that `nproc` needs to be used, there exist a couple of options to find where it is defined.

A search through the documentation can help: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/search/?q=nprocs

Without leaving the Julia REPL, and even before `nprocs` gets imported in your session, you can use [`apropos`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.5/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#Base.Docs.apropos) in order to find more about it and determine that it is needed to import the `Distributed` package:

```julia
julia> apropos("nprocs")
Distributed.nprocs
Distributed.addprocs
Distributed.nworkers
```

An other way of using apropos is via the [help REPL mode](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.5/stdlib/REPL/#Help-mode):

```julia
julia> # type `?` when the cursor is right after the prompt to enter help REPL mode

# note the use of double quotes to trigger "apropos" instead of a regular help query
help?> "nprocs"
Distributed.nprocs
Distributed.addprocs
Distributed.nworkers
```

Previous options work well in the case of `nprocs` because it is part of the standard library. [JuliaHub](https://juliahub.com) is another option which allows looking for things more broadly, in the entire Julia ecosystem. As an example, looking for `nprocs` in JuliaHub's "Doc Search" tool also returns relevant results: https://juliahub.com/ui/Documentation?q=nprocs

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I'll leave this up for anyone else who is having this problem.

The solution is to import the Distributed package using:

`using Distributed`

Why this is not included in the documentation I do not know.

Comment: yes and `Distributed` is a built-in package. other usefull packages include SharedArrays, ParallelDataTransfer.jl, DistributedArrays.jl, ClusterManagers.jl.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel thank you for this helpful information